# Can I specify the edge lengths of a simplicial polyhedron?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

Let $X$ be a convex polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose faces are all triangles, and let $\ell$ be a function which assigns a positive real number to each edge of $X$.

We say that $\ell$ is ***realizable*** if there exists a convex polyhedron isomorphic to $X$ whose corresponding edge lengths are given by $\ell$.

My question is:

> Under what conditions will $\ell$ be realizable?

There are two obvious conditions that $\ell$ must satisfy:

1. For each triangle $a,b,c$ of edges, the numbers $\ell(a),\ell(b),\ell(c)$ must satisfy the triangle inequality.
2. If we compute the "angles" of each triangle using the law of cosines, then the sum of the angles at any vertex must be less than $2\pi$.

Are these conditions sufficient?  Or are there hidden obstructions to specifying the edge lengths of a simplicial polyhedron?

**Note:** I'm pretty sure the given conditions *are* sufficient in the case where $X$ is a tetrahedron (see the argument in my comment below), so the first case that I'm not sure about is the octahedron.

Comment: For tetrahedron, we know the lengths are realizable if and only if the edge lengths of each face satisfies triangle inequality and corresponding Cayley-Menger determinant is positive. However, it is not clear to me whether your condition 2 is equivalent to the condition on Calyer-Menger determinant or not.

Comment: @achillehui There is a reasonably simple geometric proof that the given conditions are sufficient for tetrahedra.  Imagine that we take the base triangle and attach the three triangles to its sides as "flaps".  For each pair of flaps, either they can be rotated to a position where corresponding sides coincide, or they can't.  If any two flaps can be rotated into position, we are done.  If no pair of flaps can be rotated into position, it must be because all three flaps can be rotated to the interior of the base triangle without touching, in which case the sum of the opposite angles is $>2\pi$.

Comment: I see, your argument does seem to work.

Comment: @achillehui However, I do _not_ know whether the conditions are sufficient for an octahedron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. According to [Fedorchuk and Pak](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1127831442) (see section 2.6), this is a theorem of Aleksandrov. Fedorchuk and Pak say

> Until recently, [Aleksandrov's] work was somewhat overlooked in the West. Even now [2005] there is no published exposition of the proof in English. The interested reader should consult [Aleksandrov's book] or its German translation.

(Things in square brackets are my own insertions.)

Aleksandrov's book was published in Russian in 1950 and [translated into English](http://books.google.com/books?id=R9vPatr5aqYC) in 2005 (confusingly, Fedorchuk and Pak cite the English translation, although they state that no English exposition is available). Skimming Chapter 4 suggests it has a proof. Aleksandrov gives several references to earlier papers but, unfortunately, Google Books has not included his bibliography!

---

There is an easier fact which proved in 1916 by Dehn, which is that your result is infinitesimally true. (Dehn, "Über die Strakheit knovexer Polyeder." *Math. Ann.* **77**, 466-473, (1916). Does not appear to be available digitally.) Namely, fix $\Delta$ a combinatorial type of triangulated sphere, with $n$ vertices, so $3n-6$ edges. The set of all convex embeddings of $\Delta$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3n}$; call it $\tilde{U}(\Delta)$. Taking the lengths of edges gives a smooth map $\ell: \tilde{U}(\Delta) \to \mathbb{R}^{3n-6}$. Dehn's theorem is that the [Jacobian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of this map has rank $3n-6$, and thus, by the [multivariate implicit function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem), it is locally left-invertible.

A different aspect of this result is usually emphasized. Pick a vertex $v$, edge $e$ containing $v$ and face $f$ containing $e$ in $\Delta$. We can normalize our polytopes by assuming that $v$ is at $(0,0,0)$, the edge $e$ is parallel to the $x$-axis and the face $f$ is in the $(x,y,z)$ plane. Let $U(\Delta)$ be the subset of $\tilde{U}(\Delta)$ with this normalization. Then $\dim U(\Delta) = 3n-6$ (three dimensions of translation and three of rotation were normalized from $\tilde{U}(\Delta)$). So $\ell: U(\Delta) \to \mathbb{R}^{3n-6}$ is a map between spaces of the same dimension, and Dehn's theorem states that the Jacobian matrix of the map is invertible. People usually focus on the fact that this means that you can't "flex" $\Delta$: There is no infinitesimal motion of $\Delta$ which keeps all the edge lengths constant, other than translations and rotations.

For a short proof of Dehn's theorem, see Pak, [*A short proof of rigidity of convex polytopes*](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602579).

Comment: Many thanks for this answer.  I was aware of Dehn's theorem, but couldn't figure out whether the stronger result was true.  (Presumably there is no analogous stronger result for non-simplicial polytopes.)

Comment: There is a general technique for turning theorems like Dehn's into what you want. Let $V(\Delta)$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3n-6}$ which you want to prove is $\ell(U(\Delta))$. (1) Show that $\ell: U(\Delta) \to V(\Delta)$ is proper http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map. This implies $\ell(U(\Delta))$ is closed in $V(\Delta)$. (2) Dehn's result implies $\ell(U(\Delta))$ is open in $V(\Delta)$. (3) Show that $V(\Delta)$ is connected. I was going to try this, but (3) was destroying me; I'm glad I googled to see if someone else had done it.

Comment: WARNING: I am no longer sure that I have read Fedorchuk and Pak correctly. In particular, I am not sure whether something subtle is happening in the translation from a list of edge lengths to a metric space. I can't seem to deduce, just from the given statements, that the triangle inequality is satisfied when the edge graph of $G$ contains a $3$-cycle which does not bound a face.